# Am I misunderstanding Projections in HotChocolate?

Tags: c#, sql, graphql, hotchocolate

I cant seem to get Projections with HotChocolate working for GraphQl. According to the documentation Projections should prevent over-requesting of data from the DB, and help connect data in related tables. As a simple example I set up the following:

```
public class Name
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}


public class Queries
{
    [UseProjection]
    [UseDbContext(typeof(DbAccess))]
    public IQueryable<Name> GetNames([ScopedService] DbAccess db)
    {
        return db.Names;
    }
}

public class NameType : ObjectType<Name>
{ }
```

In Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
        services.AddGraphQLServer()
            .AddType<NameType>()
            .AddQueryType<Queries>()
            .AddProjections();
```

So with this set up and I run a Graphql query like :
{names{firstName}}

I would expect the sql generated to be something like

```
SELECT `n`.`FirstName` FROM `Names` AS `n`
```

Instead though it does

```
SELECT `n`.`Id`, `n`.`FirstName`, `n`.`LastName` FROM `Names` AS `n`
```

Is there some obvious thing that I am missing?

Edit for versions:

```
NetCore 5.0
EfCore 5.0.12
HotChocolate 11.0.7
Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql 5.0.3
```

Comment: This is pretty much how it works. What version of EFCore, .NET and HotChocolate are you using?

Comment: Hahah well I'm glad I'm not just dumb :P I have added the versions for all the lib that are being used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out after much trial and error that I had the attribute tags in the wrong order should be:

```
public class Queries
{
  [UseDbContext(typeof(DbAccess))]
  [UseProjection]
  public IQueryable<Name> GetNames([ScopedService] DbAccess db)
  {
    return db.Names;
  }
}
```